# How to always keep one EC2 instance in an auto-scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I have an auto scaling group at AWS with a few instances. I'd like to define one to be the primary one, where I'll also configure custom scripts to be run on it.

I thought I would enable the "termination protection" for this EC2 instance but it seems that this did not avoid it to be deleted by the Auto scaling group a few moments later.

Is there a way I can have an EC2 instance that is affected to the Auto-scaling group to always stay on ?

(Note: I want it to be accessible via the Load balancer, but I can't detach it from the auto scaling group because the CodeDeploy systeme I have implemented won't work with it?)

Comment: What kind of termination policy did you set? That should prevent the instance from being stopped

Comment: Termination policy prevents the instance from being stopped/terminated. Could you specify how/what termination policy did you set?

Comment: I did not set any specific termination policy,but upon checking, it's on "`Default`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you have put `Instance scale-in protection` from `autoscaling group -> Advanced configurations`. This only put `scale-in protection` for new instances and not on the instances already `inservice`. If you want to put `scale-in protection` on a specific instance, you need to do `Instance Management -> actions -> Set scale-in protection`. This way your specific instance will not be terminated, even if you set `Desired capacity` to `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is exactly what I was looking for!